# Kotlin: What is the difference between = vs ==?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to set a certain value, `monsterHealth`, to display `0` instead of a negative number. If I'm trying to reassign the value to show `0` instead of, say, `-2`, would I want to use `=` or `==`?

Comment: `=` is an assignment, `==` is a comparison for equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are different operators:

- `=` - assignment operator,
- `==` and `!=` - equality operators,
- `===` and `!==` - referential equality operators.

also

- `val` - read only variable/property (it cannot be reassigned/changed),
- `var` - mutable variable/property.

[Kotlin Documentation - Keywords and operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols)

Comment: Thanks! I tried looking it up in the documentation, but I could never find out which was used for what.

Comment: The IDE will literally tell you if you use the wrong one!